# Get month and year from Joda's LocalDate

Tags: java, jodatime

From a LocalDate I want to get only the month-year string.
E.g “March 2015”
Right now I do it as follows:

```
myDate.monthOfYear().getAsText(LOCALE) + " " + myDate.year().getAsText(LOCALE);
```

Is there a simpler/better way to do it?

Comment: If your code works and you are looking for improvements then you should probably post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just create an appropriate formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
    .forPattern("MMMM yyyy")
    .withLocale(LOCALE);

String text = formatter.print(myDate);
```